# Change the day names in title to single letter in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetime picker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I want to change the header of the week to a single letter like below:

```
S M T W T F S
```

[image: Image example]

Does anyone know any property to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap eonasdan-datetimepicker relies on momentjs and it uses moment to get the localized names of the days of the week (see [`fillDow`](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/v4.17.45/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L503) function in the source: it uses `currentDate.format('dd')` to get short name of the day of the week via moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)).

Moment lets you customize localized short names using `updateLocale` and the `weekdaysMin` key as explained in the Customize -> [Minimal Weekday Abbreviations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/weekday-min/) section of the docs.

Here a complete working sample:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  weekdaysMin : ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]
});
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```